# How to stack numpy arrays alternately/slicewise along a specific axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I stack arrays in an alternating fashion? Consider the following example with three arrays:

```
import numpy as np
one = np.ones((5, 2, 2))
two =  np.ones((5, 2, 2))*2
three = np.ones((5, 2, 2))*3
```

I would like to create a new array `result` with shape `(15, 2, 2)` which is formed by alternately taking a slice from each of the given arrays, i.e. the result should look like:

```
result[0] = one[0]
result[1] = two[0]
result[2] = three[0]
result[3] = one[1]
result[4] = two[1]
result[5] = three[1]
result[6] = one[2]
etc...
```

The arrays above are just an example to illustrate the question, I am not looking for a way to create this specific result array. What is the easiest way to achieve this, at best with specifying a stacking axis?

Of course, it is possible to do some loops but it seems rather inconvenient...

Comment: or `np.concatenate((ones, twos, threes), 1).reshape(15,2,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and then reshape (with -1 for the first axis appended with the lengths along last two axes for a generic solution) -

```
np.hstack([one,two,three]).reshape((-1,)+one.shape[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wanne take a look at `np.stack()` i.e.:

```
np.stack([one, two, three], axis=1).reshape(15, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for np.vstack

```
np.vstack((one,two,three))
```

Read more about it here [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Answer (score 0):

With selectable axis:

```
# example arrays
a,b,c = np.multiply.outer([1,2,3],np.ones((5,2,2)))
# axis
k = 1

np.stack([a,b,c],k+1).reshape(*(-(k==j) or s for j,s in enumerate(a.shape)))
# array([[[1., 1.],
#         [2., 2.],
#         [3., 3.],
#         [1., 1.],
#         [2., 2.],
#         [3., 3.]],
#  
#        [[1., 1.],
...
```